# Extremely long Rx event chains

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I'm working on something that can best be described as a simulation/workflow/game logic engine (although it doesn't fall squarely into any of those categories).

The intention is for it to be completely event driven (reactive), and must support the possibility of tens or even hundreds of thousands of chained events, with branching and filtering and concurrency, and all that Rx goodness.

I'm *very* new to Reactive Extensions, and decided to write the simplest test I could think of (chain a bunch of ISubjects together).  I quickly found that chaining together too many events (about 12000 in my case) results in a StackOverflowException -- which makes sense to me when considering Rx is really just wiring event handlers together in novel ways, and call stacks can only get so deep.

So I'm looking for a (Reactive-ish?) way around this limitation.  I can't be the only one who wants to do something extremely large with this framework.  Any help the community can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1000)
        {
            Console.Write($"{i} ");
            using (Dynamite dynamite = new Dynamite())
            {
                dynamite.Setup(i);
                dynamite.Trigger();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class Dynamite : IDisposable
{
    ISubject<bool> start = null;
    IList<IDisposable> handles = new List<IDisposable>();

    public void Setup(int length)
    {
        length = length == 0 ? 1 : length;

        var fuses =
            Enumerable.Range(0, length)
            .Select(v => new Subject<bool>())
            .ToArray();

        ISubject<bool> prev = null;

        foreach (var fuse in fuses)
        {
            //Console.Write(".");

            if (prev != null)
            {
                Attach(prev, fuse);
            }
            prev = fuse;
        }

        start = fuses.First();
        var end = fuses.Last();

        handles.Add(
            end
                .Subscribe(onNext: b =>
                {
                    //Console.Write("t");
                    this.Explode();
                }));
    }

    void Attach(ISubject<bool> source, ISubject<bool> dest)
    {
        var handle = source
            .Subscribe(onNext: b =>
             {
                 //Console.Write("s");
                 dest.OnNext(b);
             });
        handles.Add(handle);
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        //Console.Write("p");
        start.OnNext(true);
    }

    void Explode()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("...BOOM!");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var h in handles)
            h.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here's the console output:

```
0 ...BOOM!
1000 ...BOOM!
2000 ...BOOM!
3000 ...BOOM!
4000 ...BOOM!
5000 ...BOOM!
6000 ...BOOM!
7000 ...BOOM!
8000 ...BOOM!
9000 ...BOOM!
10000 ...BOOM!
11000 ...BOOM!
12000
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  The [CurrentThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242963(v=vs.103).aspx) scheduler.

```
.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
```

> The CurrentThreadScheduler [...] will schedule actions to be performed on the thread that makes the original call. The action is not executed immediately, but is placed in a queue and only executed after the current action is complete.

Comment: Can you explain how this is the answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity Since each operation in the sequence will be scheduled, it won't be executed immediately in the same CallStack. This will prevent the StackOverFlowException from happening.

Comment: Is there another option?

Comment: @ErinLoy - I don't understand your explanation. Can you explain how, since each operation in the sequence is scheduled, and that using `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)` will make it use the same call stack **(which it doesn't)**, how this works?

Comment: @Enigmativity In a single threaded scenario, Rx uses the ImmediateScheduler by default, which simply invokes the OnNext action, making of the current stack.  Chain enough of these together and you overflow the stack.

Comment: My solution was to use the CurrentThread scheduler instead, which is intended  to constrain the pipeline to the current thread, in a multithreaded scenario.  In my single threaded scenario, breaking out of the current call stack is really just a side effect of how the scheduler functions.

Comment: I haven't peeked into the internals of the scheduler, but I assume there's some kind of queue-and-loop mechanism that does this.  This implies a performance impact, but my workloads will be orders of magnitude more heavy than the event plumbing, so not really a concern in my case.  Also, when I get into multithreaded events, this style of scheduling will be the default (only?) option.

Comment: @ErinLoy - You've got a lot of this wrong. The `ImmediateScheduler` is not the default for Rx. Depending on the operator you're using you'll get different default schedulers. Next the `CurrentThread` scheduler doesn't constrain to the current thread (which does seem counter-intuitive) - instead it constrains itself to the thread that the subscription was created on and this is dependant again on the operators used so you can get some unexpected results. Bottom-line is that it's not the necessarily thread in which the observable pipeline was define or initially subscribed on.

Comment: Thank you for making these distinctions - I'm sure they will be important in a multi-threaded context.  In my case, I believe the Immediate scheduler was in use (rule of least concurrency, with no exotic operators in the pipeline, and no threading in the mix).  The CurentThread scheduler addressed my need by introducing a queue to break up the call stack.  Is there a better approach for my (not production focused) test scenario?